# Embed image in post from external url

Tags: posts, images, urls

Is there a way in Wordpress that I can embed an image to a post when I want to include it like this:

```
<img src="....." />
```

So I want to add this manually. Is this possible? Now, I get the URL, without the image. So the embedding process isn't done.

PS: I am using a **front-end editor.**

Comment: Did you try inserting the HTML Code in Text Mode?

Comment: Yes. I edited my question.

Comment: What exactly is your front-end editor? That's not a standard WordPress feature and typically off-topic for this forum.

Comment: I am using User Submitted Posts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the **Text / HTML** tab selected when you input HTML, not the **Visual** tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question... I think it's important to know that I am using a front-end editor.